# berkely xml db as embedded db from java

Tags: java, berkeley-db-xml

I am looking around for some nice xml db , which would be embedded in my application.
I want to use berkley db as embedded from my java application.
That is i don't want to run berkley db as a service and access it , rather i want to embed from my application and then use it.
Is this possible.
I looked around but couldn't find any example or something.

I found - http://fluent.exist-db.org/ which fits the bill , but i was seeing if berkley can give similar feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly how BDB XML is intended to be used. Did you read the [Getting started guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17276_01/html/gsg_xml/java/index.html)?